# How to overwrite sphinx/locale/{language}/LC_MESSAGES/sphinx.po?

Tags: localization, python-sphinx, gettext, po

I'd like to overwrite admonition labels.
Admonitions are directives such as `note`, `warning`, and so on.

For Japanese, the labels are defined in
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/sphinx.po.

Is there a simple way to overwrite them without changing the master repository?

Comment: I don't know, but I would start by reading the documentation at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html. If that does not help, then I would search its [issue tracker](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues), and if none is relevant then create a new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me (tested with Sphinx 3.3.1):

1. Copy the Japanese **sphinx.po** from  **<sphinx_install_dir>/sphinx/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/**

   to **<your_sphinx_proj>/locales/ja/LC_MESSAGES/**.

   Note the directory name **locales** (the default value of the `locale_dirs` configuration option).
2. Edit `msgstr` for the relevant entries (admonitions in this case) in the copy of **sphinx.po**.

   It is not necessary to keep the entire copy. You can remove the unchanged entries if you want.
3. Run sphinx-build with `language=ja` (set it in conf.py or on the command line). A local project-specific **sphinx.mo** file is generated and used in the build.

This means that there will be two *.mo files for the same domain ("sphinx"). The local sphinx.mo is consulted first, and the original sphinx.mo that comes with Sphinx is used as the fallback.